# How to update records partially in django without specifying whole fields?

Tags: python, django

I am using `save()` method to create records in Django. Same `save()` method along with primary key is used to update the corresponding record. But every time I can't specify values of all fields in the update. This is removing the already existing data, that I added during creation. So what is the best way to perform the partial update by specifying only required fields.?

## MODEL

```
class ApprenticeUsers(models.Model):

   uid = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
   apid = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=False)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False)
```

## VIEWS

```
def insert_apprenticeship_data(user_details, table_obj):


  table_obj = table_obj()
  for field in  user_details:
     setattr(table_obj,field, user_details[field])
  try:    
     table_obj.save()
  except:
     return False
```

## SAMPLE DATA PASSING TO VIEW

```
({uid:123, apid:"AP12"}, ApprenticeUsers)
```

*Here uid is the primary key*

Comment: You need to show your code. Normally this wouldn't happen, so you are doing something unusual.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have updated the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal pattern is to retrieve the item from the database, update the relevant fields, and save it back. You are missing the first step, and are constructing a new item each time.

Note that a much better way of achieving what you want is to use a ModelForm; in addition to updating, it will also take care of validating that the data is as it should be. Or, if this is an API, you could use django-rest-framework to write a Serializer that does the same thing.

Comment: Please excuse me. Currently I am developing an API without any framework. I know I can retrieve and update the record, but it will be double work by fetching and then updating, Is there any workaround to avoid first fetch section?

Answer (score 4):

The model `.save()` method has a parameter `update_fields` which also you to specify which fields should be updated on save. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save

Comment: For this I need to fetch the record and then update, but this will be costly for me

Comment: What do you expect to be costly about fetching a record by its PK and updating it?

Comment: I am building an API and it should be fast enough, so fetching a record and then updating it won't possible